# Wasserstein GAN critic training ambiguity

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm running a DCGAN-based GAN, and am experimenting with WGANs, but am a bit confused about how to train the WGAN.

In the official [Wasserstein GAN PyTorch implementation](https://github.com/martinarjovsky/WassersteinGAN/blob/master/main.py), the discriminator/critic is said to be trained `Diters` (usually 5) times per each generator training.

Does this mean that the critic/discriminator trains on `Diters` *batches* or the *whole dataset* `Diters` times? If I'm not mistaken, the official implementation suggests the discriminator/critic is trained on the *whole dataset* `Diters` times, but other implementations of WGAN (in PyTorch and TensorFlow etc.) do the opposite.

Which is correct? [The WGAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07875.pdf) (to me, at least), indicates that it is `Diters` *batches*. Training on the whole dataset is obviously orders of magnitude slower.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The correct is to consider an iteration as a batch. 
In the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07875.pdf), for each iteration of the critic/discriminator they are sampling a batch of size `m` of the real data and  a batch of size `m` of prior samples `p(z)` to work it. After the critic is trained over `Diters` iterations, they train the generator which also starts by the sampling of a batch of prior samples of `p(z)`.
Therefore, each iteration is working on a batch.

In the [official implementation](https://github.com/martinarjovsky/WassersteinGAN/blob/master/main.py) this is also happening. What may be confusing is that they use the variable name `niter` to represent the number of epochs to train the model. Although they use a different scheme to set `Diters` at lines [162](https://github.com/martinarjovsky/WassersteinGAN/blob/f81eafd2aa41e93698f203732f8f395abc70be02/main.py#L162)-166:

```
# train the discriminator Diters times
    if gen_iterations < 25 or gen_iterations % 500 == 0:
        Diters = 100
    else:
        Diters = opt.Diters
```

they are, as in the paper, training the critic over `Diters` batches.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of WGAN shows it as Diter batches for the discriminator for each run of the generator - https://github.com/shayneobrien/generative-models/blob/74fbe414f81eaed29274e273f1fb6128abdb0ff5/src/w_gan.py#L88